# Cassandra 3.11 read performance issue

Tags: cassandra, time-series

My Client is running with a 5node production cluster of version Apache Cassandra 3.11.. They are maintaining timeseries data, One particular table is having data stored upto 1TB data which is the bigggest among others ;; it is using Murmur3Partitioner as the partitioning strategy ..Client needs to display the data with 0second lag ( Means upon the click they need to display the data there should not be any waittime ) irrespective of duration ( timeframe ) they are supplying as input .. Is it possible in Cassandra to do like that.. What are the things I need to check in this situation from Cassandra Database end..

```
Anyhelp on this would be a huge learning for me

5 node communication (gossiping ) is happening properly .. Data retreival needs to be faster .. Front end application is running in Python
```

Below is the table structure of 1TB data table:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.tablename (
        sensorid text,
        systemid int,
        year double,
        date date,
        timestampvalue timestamp,
        extradetails map<text, text>,
        parkid int,
        value float,
        PRIMARY KEY ((sensorid, systemid, year), date, timestampvalue)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC, timestampvalue DESC)
        AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': '60000'}
        AND comment = 'It will store whole sensor data'
        AND compaction = {'base_time_seconds': '21600', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.DateTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
        AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
        AND default_time_to_live = 0
        AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
        AND max_index_interval = 2048
        AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
        AND min_index_interval = 128
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
        AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Can you edit your question, providing the table's primary key definition and the query which isn't performing well?

Comment: Hi Aaron edited the QN.

Answer (score 0):

> 5 node production cluster of version Apache Cassandra 3.11

For optimal data distribution, it's always better to size clusters as a factor of the RF.  So if the RF=3, good cluster sizes are 3, 6, 9, etc.

> 0 second lag ( Means upon the click they need to display the data there should not be any waittime )

> irrespective of duration ( timeframe ) they are supplying as input

> Is it possible in Cassandra to do like that.

Wow.  A lot to unpack here.

First of all, querying with zero latency (lag) isn't possible with *any* database.  There will always be time spent when reading data over a network, seeking, and pulling data from a disk.  Here's a link that might help with understanding that: [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://colin-scott.github.io/personal_website/research/interactive_latency.html)

When data modeling for a distributed database (like Apache Cassandra) you need to know the queries which will be run, first.  I did ask for the query to be added to the question, but all I see is the table definition.  Given that definition, this is the query that can be supported:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE sensorid=? AND systemid=? AND year=?;
```

All 3 of those keys are required on every query.  If they are not, and something like `ALLOW FILTERING` is being done, that's going to go really slow.

Additional queries can be run by providing the clustering keys as well, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE sensorid=? AND systemid=? AND year=?
AND date=? AND timestamp>? AND timestamp<?;
```

Providing additional filtering on the clustering keys should help things run a little faster.

Something else to consider, is how big are the partitions?

```
PRIMARY KEY ((sensorid, systemid, year)
```

This partition key means that all data recorded for a specific `sensorid`/`systemid` combination over a year will be stored together in a single partition.  Not sure how much data that's going to be, but Cassandra has some hard limits around that.  First, it maxes out at 2 billion cells per partition (a key and each of its column values count as cells).  Secondly, If this amount of data is > 100MB, that's going to get slow fast.

If that is really big (> 1GB), you should consider adding `date` into the partition key:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((sensorid, systemid, year, date)
```

At least then you'll cut down the size of the partition by a factor of 365.  Of course, you'll then be limited to querying a single day at a time, or using the `IN` operator or some other approach for multiple days.

The secret to building a high-performing, distributed data model is in keeping things small.  Small partitions, small column values, small result sets, etc.  The smaller you can keep everything, the happier the users will be.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for lighting me up.. Your answer has given me some clarity to proceed with.. Currently RF factor is 3 for 5 node cluster running in Ubuntu 18 version ( On Premise Server ) Other problem that I could see is While reading data i.e; when co ordinator node asks for data from other nodes the timeout is happening at that point  ( Eg : if node A is being queried for a data and Node A asks for data from Node C in the cluster ; Operation timeout is happening ) Below are the timeout settings Current timeout for type read: 60000 ms